# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, google-play-services

ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

> Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1
>   -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@[15.0 .1], but play-services-base version was 16.0.1.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.studentattendance"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your dependency list.

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Would you kindly clarify what you did exactly. The answer if it is an answer is not clear at all.